# iFrame in Bootstrap Modal Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, iframe, bootstrap-modal

I am loading an iFrame of another page(not in Angular code) in my Angular component's Valor's Bootstrap Modal. What I want to achieve is that, an action in the iFrame must trigger a function in my Angular component. I have looked at various similar questions (which suggested using the window or parent objects) but I was not able to obtain a workable solution for this particular use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is so simple, I need to enable cross frame access that is not safe. So I went on by using postMessage to securely transfer data via cross-frame.